# REGEXP in MySQL Return unwanted value

Tags: java, regex, mysql

I have problem using REGEX in Mysql

I have oid value in database like this

### id  ->  value

1.3.6.1.4.1 ->  Value a

1.3.6.1.4.1.2499.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1    ->  Value b

1.3.6.1.4.1.2499    ->  Value c

And my objecttives are
1. To get single oid & value with the specific oid that i put into sql statement
2. If no specific value then it should reverse the oid number by number until it found the newrest value

For example
If i use
    [*select id  from tablename  where '1.3.6.1.4.1.2499.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1' REGEXP oid*]
    it should return only 1.3.6.1.4.1.2499.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1 but **the above sql will return all result**

If i use 
    [*select id from tablename  where '1.3.6.1.4.1.24999999.5' REGEXP oid*]
    it should return 1.3.6.1.4.1 only but **it return 1.3.6.1.4.1 and  1.3.6.1.4.1.2499**

If i use 
    select id from tablename  where '1.3.6.1.4.1.2499.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.100' REGEXP oid
    it should return 1.3.6.1.4.1.2499 only but it **return all ids**

I am not really familiar with this REGEXP. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL, you should use `field REGEXP value`, like this:

```
select id from tablename where oid REGEXP '1.3.6.1.4.1.2499.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1'
```

`.` must be escaped with `\`
And to match an entire row, use `^` and `$`:

```
select id from tablename where oid REGEXP '^1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.2499\.1\.1\.2\.1\.1\.1\.1\.1$'
```

I don't understand why do you use `REGEXP` when you can select by `LIKE`, because you don't search by a regular expression.

Comment: Thank you. Solve 1 problem but but if I do like this
select id from tablename where oid REGEXP '^1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.2499\.1\.1\.2\.1\.1\.1\.1\.100$', it should return 1.3.6.1.4.1.2499

I don use LIKE because it cannot get "1.3.6.1.4.1.2499" --> it is the nearest answer in the database.

Comment: Does this work? `select id from tablename where oid REGEXP '^1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.2499(\.1\.1\.2\.1\.1\.1\.1\.100)?$'`

Comment: Ya.. it is working... Unfortunately i don't know  where should we put the bracket. It is dynamic.
2 thumbs up for u!

Comment: Depends on what rule that code is: maybe you should put it after the sixth `.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think regex is the right tool for this job.

Instead, I'd loop over the input string, treating it as a period-delimited list.

Match the list against oid.  If zero matches, remove the last list element.  Repeat.